# pg_basebackup: directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data" exists but is not empty

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos6, high-availability

I am trying to build a HA two node cluster with pacemaker and corosync for postgresql-9.3. I am using the link below as my guide.

> http://kb.techtaco.org/#!linux/postgresql/building_a_highly_available_multi-node_cluster_with_pacemaker_&_corosync.md

However, I cannot get pass to the part where I need do pg_basebackup as shown below.

> [root@TKS-PSQL01 ~]# runuser -l postgres -c 'pg_basebackup -D
>   /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data -l `date +"%m-%d-%y"`_initial_cloning -P -h
>   TKS-PSQL02 -p 5432 -U replicator -W -X stream' pg_basebackup:
>   directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data" exists but is not empty

/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data in TKS-PSQL02 is confirmed empty.

> [root@TKS-PSQL02 9.3]# ls -l /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/ total 0

Any idea why I am getting such error? And is there any better way to do Postgresql HA? Note: I am not using shared storage for the database so I could not proceed with Redhat clustering.

Appreciate all the answers in advance.

Comment: My apologies, I found the answer for the error. I should be running the command on standby node. Now awaiting for better way to do the HA for postgresql.